# How to change the owner/permission of device files?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

For example `/dev/loop*`, `/dev/raw/*`, etc., they are automatically reset to `root/root` after rebooted.

Change the owner/permission of device files maybe not a good idea, though. I just want to know if it is possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Write a udev rule](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) that sets the permissions on the device node appropriately.